# Using the .modify XML method in SQL returning syntax error

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am working in SQL Server 2016 and trying to update the  element value in my XML column for numerous records and getting a syntax error but can't figure out where the problem  is.  I've googled and tried a number of fixes but to no avail.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks. Here are the details:

Here is my XML:

```
<IW>
  <form name="INSTALLMENT LATE BILLING" version="2" blkflg="0">
    <MonthlyPayment>260.34</MonthlyPayment>
    <BillingFee>7.91</BillingFee>
    <LateFee>13.00</LateFee>
    <BillDate>12/23/2021</BillDate>
    <DueDate>12/23/2021</DueDate>
    <LateDate>12/24/2021</LateDate>
    <CancelDate>01/04/2022</CancelDate>
  </form>
</IW>
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
UPDATE dt
    SET dt.DocumentData.modify('replace value of (/IW/form/CancelDate/text())[1] with "01/09/2022"')
        , dt.CancelDate = '2022-01-09'
    --SELECT  dt.CancelDate AS DocTransCancellationDate
    --  , p.CancelDate AS PolicyCancellationDate
    --  , p.PolicyNo
    --  , dt.DocumentData
    --  , dt.*
    FROM dbo.AUT_DocumentTransaction dt
    JOIN dbo.AUT_Policy p ON dt.PolicySysID = p.PolicySysID
    WHERE dt.DocumentTransactionSysID IN (45601342
        ,45601349
        ,45601354
        ,45601356
        ,45601357
        ,45601359
        ,45601360
        ,45601363
        ,45601364
        ,45601365
        ,45601366)
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 377
Incorrect syntax near 'modify'.
```

Comment: Larnu, the column is dt.DocumentData, it is an XML column in the table.  Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: Got it.  When I modified the code as you described, now I'm getting this error:  A non-mutator method is expected in this context.  I'll try and google for a solution to that.  Thanks.

Comment: It's the qualifier. Remove that and it works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb1699af280d9976c3a50f7539d84005) . Apologies, I gave incorrect advice before.

Comment: @Larnu Oh, I really don't like that syntax rule. "The only way you can get this to work is to be _less_ precise about what you mean."

Comment: Yeah, It stumped me for a "hot minute" too, @AaronBertrand , and adding a qualifier like that really should not cause such a misleading error. I, personally, feel like it's actually a bug. Though, I suppose the "excuse" will be that you've already defined what table you mean "precisely" in the `UPDATE` clause (though that doesn't mean I agree with such an excuse).

Comment: Thank you @Larnu.  Your time and help are appreciated.  That worked.  Also, I appreciated Aaron Bertrand's comments.